# Оптимальный алгоритм оперирования входами(жадный алгоритм выбора входов) bitcoin

Tags: алгоритм, bitcoin, transaction, protocol

Подскажите, какой алгоритм используют bitcoin кошельки для подсчета оптимального кол-ва входов для достижения нужной суммы транзакции с учетом комиссии.

Входные данные:

1. Сумма монет, которые требуется отправить.
2. Список не потраченных входов отсортированный по возрастанию монет.

Алгоритм на основании требуемой суммы сам подбирает необходимые входы для совершения транзакции.

И как быть в том случае, если у меня накопится много входов с маленькими суммами, комиссия которых больше имеющейся суммы. Тогда имея 1000 отдельных входов номиналом по 1 сатоши, мы не сможем их потратить, поэтому они будут бесконечно лежать в кошельке?

Comment: Это немного модифицированная задача о рюкзаке (knapsack по англ) https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D1%80%D1%8E%D0%BA%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5

Comment: А по поводу 1 сатоши, все верно. Алгоритм не должен брать сумму на выходе, он должен брать (сумма - потенциальная комиссия за добавление этого выхода в транзакцию). На выходах с маленькими суммами эта величина будет отрицательная, а значит нет смысла добавлять их в транзакцию.

Comment: Спасибо, задача о рюкзаке подходит. 
Хотел уточнить, с каждым добавлением нового входа комиссия будет расти линейно? Ведь вычисляется она "сатоши/байт", а входы имеют примерно одинаковый вес. Верно? 

Второй вопрос. Касаемо 1 сатоши. Алгоритм выбрал оптимальные входы и получилось так, что в остатке нам вернется 1 сатоши. Есть ли смысл его возвращать, или стоит написать условие, что если остаток меньше стоимости комиссии, то не возвращать его? Как действуют реальные кошельки? Ведь хранение таких входов будет показывать нам рост баланса, а на деле это только в убыток.

Comment: Да, входы имеют примерно одинаковый вес. Зависит от типа адреса. Оставлять 1 сатоши так же нет смысла, проще списать его в комиссию. Каждый выход занимает некоторое количество байт, а за каждый байт в транзакции нужно платить.

Comment: @Zergatul Благодарю. Вопрос решен. Напоследок - ссылок на github с алгоритмом в других кошельках у Вас нет в запасе? (С++/python/etc)
Интересно посмотреть как другие люди решили этот вопрос.

Comment: Нет, я сам не интересовался детально этим. В bitcoin core клиенте вроде есть хорошая реализация, которую недавно апгрейдили.

Comment: Оформил все комментарии в ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если кратко описать, то получится такой алгоритм:

1. Для каждого неиспользованного выхода считаем, сколько байт займет использование этого выхода в новой транзакции. В зависимости от типа транзакции (segwit или обычная), типа адресов (P2PKH, P2SH) это количество может различаться.
2. Для каждого выхода считаем значение: `сумма_на_выходе - кол-во_байт_из_шага_1 * комисиия_за_байт`. В нас могут получиться отрицательные значения. Использовать их нет смысла. Возможно в будущем комиссия за байт уменьшиться, и мы сможем их использовать.
3. Полученные значения прогоняем через модифицированную [задачу о рюкзаке](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D1%80%D1%8E%D0%BA%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5). В нас есть `N` значений (`o1`, `o2`, ..., `oN` из шага 2), и нам нужно найти такое подмножество, что бы его сумма была минимальной, и большей или равной заданной величине `m` (количество биткоинов, которые мы хотим отправить).

Если превышение величины `m` получилось небольшое, может получиться так, что нет смысла его возвращать себе. Каждый выход транзакции занимает некоторое количество байт и за них так же нужно платить. Исходя из комиссии за байт, величины остатка и размера выхода в байтах принимаем решение, добавлять выход, или списать остаток в дополнительную комиссию.